# How to retrieve full type name of method variable from ASTParser

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I want to parse interface java file with `ASTParser`, extract declared methods and get full type (including Package name) of the variables.

```
compilationUnit.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

            public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration methodVisitor) {

                if (methodVisitor != null) {

                    for (Object parameter : methodVisitor.parameters()) {
                        VariableDeclaration variableDeclaration = (VariableDeclaration) parameter;
                        String type = variableDeclaration.getStructuralProperty(SingleVariableDeclaration.TYPE_PROPERTY).toString();

                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
```

The type returned from `variableDeclaration.getStructuralProperty(SingleVariableDeclaration.TYPE_PROPERTY)`
contains just the  variable's Class name and not the package.

How can I get full type name?